# How to highlight jQuery Autocomplete results that match the text already typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've implemented jQuery Autocomplete for a client. Now they want me to highlight (e.g. make **bold**) the the portion of the result that matches the text they've typed.

e.g. the user types "something", and the results are as follows:

**something** a

**something** b

Another **something**

Do **something** else

Is this functionality built into jQuery Autocomplete? If so, what is it?

Or is this something I'll have to implement myself? If so, where do I start with that?

Comment: Which autocomplete - the one in jQuery UI, or one of the other implementations? I think the (deprecated) [bassistance.de autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) does this already, for example, but the APIs are different to plug them into your page.

Comment: @Rup: this one: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887032/how-to-highlight-input-words-in-autocomplete-jquery-ui

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same requirement previously.**

Below code may work for you.

"You need to be careful with selectors"

```
<script>
  $("#input-search-box")
    .autocomplete({
      //your code
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var items = $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item);
    //match and key variables highlight the user's typed input rendering in bold blue for dropdown items.
    var match = new RegExp("^" + this.term, "i"); //i makes the regex case insensitive

    //change initial typed characters of all item.label   replace is plain JS
    var key = item.label.replace(
      match,
      '<span class="required-drop">' + this.term + '</span>'
    );

    items.html("<a>" + key + "</a>").append(ul);
  }; 
</script>
```

Let me know if you need more help to implement this code.

Comment: add '**g**' to regex flags to highlight all matches not only one